# Hyperledger Query User1 signing

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

When I run this command,

```
fabric_client.getUserContext('user1', true);
```

I am getting this error:

> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `user1,'

can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the `query.js` script, you should see that this command is already handled,

meaning that there is no need to separately call the `getUserContex`t function as you have done in your question.

Therefore, assuming you have successfully registered and enrolled `user1`, you can continue by calling "node query.js". If successful, you should see the list of cars in the `ledger`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on fabcar example than no need to execute getUserContext command, Just call node query.js to get the result.